# How to RegisterExpectedMemoryLeak?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, fastmm

Let's start with this simple Delphi 2010 snippet:

```
var
  StringList: TStringList;
begin
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;
  StringList := TStringList.Create;
  StringList.LoadFromFile('c:\fateh.txt');
  RegisterExpectedMemoryLeak(StringList);
```

FastMM4 report the memory leak again and again even with `Addr(StringList)` as parameter
so how to Register Expected MemoryLeak and why the methods sitting above doesn't work
thank's in advance.

Comment: Don't forget to use Try after TStringList.Create (and the afferent Finally, of course).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only registered the leak of the string list object. You also need to register that you are leaking all the objects owned by the string list. In this case it owns `StringList.Count` instances of `string` objects. The memory manager does not know that those strings are owned by the string list object and so will also be leaked.

And that's much easier said than done. Because you need to find the start of the memory block that represents a string. That's at a fixed offset from the string's first character, and the offset depends on which Delphi version you use.

In Unicode Delphi, in 32 bit code, the offset is 12 bytes. So the following will register the leaked strings:

```
for i := 0 to StringList.Count-1 do 
  if StringList[i]<>'' then
    RegisterExpectedMemoryLeak(PByte(StringList[i])-12);
```

Even when you do that you'll still get two reported memory leaks. At least one of those is explained by the dynamic array that is owned by the string list, `TStringList.FList`. If you wanted to register that leak, then you'll need to do some more hacking because again you'll have to rely on implementation details as to where that array is stored.

Comment: it's a bit more complicated than what i thought from my first sight thank's David.

Comment: Maybe you could write a `TLeakyStringList` that can use it's internal knowledge to register itself. How OOP is that? ;-)